# How do I use .lower() in a list

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python and I making this quiz game and it is going well but I am very confused on how to fix the parts that don't work in the code.
To answer the questions to the code you must type a, b, c , or d (only one of them is correct) but when I type the correct letter in upper case, it says its incorrect but it says correct when I type the correct letter in lower case. I have tried things such as .lower() but i don't know how or where to put the .lower().The other problem is that I don't know how to add rounds to the quiz (e.g round 1, round 2) . I have done research but I couldn't find anything . Please help me

Here's the code

```
import random

#questions and answers
Questionnaires = {
"How many days are there in a year? \n A. 366\n B. 365\n C. 366 \n D. 363":"b",
"How many years are in a century?  \n A. 10 years \n B. 50 years \n C. 100 years \n D. 75" :"c",
"How many hours are in  a day? \n A. 24 hours \n B. 22 hours \n C. 20 hours \n D. 21 hours ":"a",
"What year is it? \n A. 2020 \n B. 2022 \n C. 2021 \n D. 2019" : "c"
}
#score counter which goes up when the user gets a question correct.   
score = 0
question = list (Questionnaires.keys())
#input answer here 
while True:
    if not question:
        break
    ques = random.choice(question)
    print(ques)
    while True:
        answer = input('Answer ' )
        # if correct, moves onto next question
        if answer == Questionnaires[ques]:
            print("Correct Answer")
            print ()
            score+=1
            print("total score is", score)
            print()
            break
        else:
            #if wrong, Asks the same question again
            print("Wrong Answer, try again")
    question.remove(ques)
```

Comment: ```lower()``` is used only for strings. Just do: ```if answer.lower() == Questionnaires[ques]```

Comment: You don't use ```lower``` on the answer in the if statement. Must be like this ```answer.lower() == Questionnaires[ques]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For making lowercase answers work,

```py
answer = input('Answer: ').lower()
```

For showing round,

```py
round = 1
while True:
    print("Round %d" % round)
    # same codes inside while loop
    round += 1
```

Comment: Modify the outer `while` loop like that.  
Put the original code inside `while` loop at `# same codes ~` part.

Answer (score 0):

replace line 34 with

```
answer = input('Answer ' ).strip().lower()
```

Comment: The `str()` function is unnecessary as the `strip()` function returns a `str` type.

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
if answer.lower() == Questionnaires[ques]:
```